# trying to write js makes whole page go blank

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html

when I use **document.write**, the whole pages goes blank and only displays the ad.

```
function __adthis(id) {
    $.getJSON('banner.php', function (data) {
        var adNum = Math.floor(Math.random() * data.ban.length);
        document.write("<SCRIPT TYPE='text/javascript'> SRC='+data.ban[0].link+'><\/SCRIPT>");
    });
}
```

this is a test, 
this is a test, 
this is a test, 
this is a test,

```
<div id="res"><script>`__adthis();`</script></div>
```

Answer (score 3):

Don't use `document.write`. Instead, use the DOM methods to create a `<script>` element and add it to the div:

```
var e = document.createElement('script');
e.setAttribute('type', 'text/javascript');
e.setAttribute('src', data.ban[0].link);
document.getElementById('res').appendChild(e);
```

Comment: thanks for this it will help me in the furture but im still getting the same issues as before :(

Comment: Same issue meaning page goes blank again?

Comment: Have a look at the script source, i.e. whatever `data.ban[0].link` contains. I'm guessing that script again includes `document.write`.

Comment: {
    "ban": [
        {
            "link": "http:\/\/ad.xtendmedia.com\/st?ad_type=ad&ad_size=300x250&section=id",
            "title": "test" 
        }
    ]
}

Comment: If you open that link in your browser, you will see that it is another JS file which uses `document.write`. Unfortunately, this no longer works with the current standards. See if you can get updated ad code from the provider.

Answer (score 0):

HTML

```
<div id="ad_goes_here" />
```

JavaScript

```
function __adthis(id){
    $.getJSON('banner.php', function(data) {
        var adNum = Math.floor(Math.random()*data.ban.length);
        $("#ad_goes_here").html("<SCRIPT TYPE='text/javascript' SRC='+data.ban[0].link+'><\/SCRIPT>");
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just a side note about why `document.write()` does not work as expected. The [W3C spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-HTML/html.html#ID-75233634) defines it this way:

> Write a string of text to a document
>   stream opened by open()

The [Mozilla developer docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/DOM/Document.write) add this remark:

> Writing to a document that has already
>   loaded without calling document.open()
>   will automatically perform a
>   document.open call. Once you have
>   finished writing, it is recommended to
>   call document.close(), to tell the
>   browser to finish loading the page.
>   The text you write is parsed into the
>   document's structure model.

In other words, using `document.write()` once the doc has been rendered triggers a [`document.open()` call](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-HTML/html.html#ID-72161170) which:

> Open a document stream for writing. If
>   a document exists in the target, this
>   method clears it.